# Postgres - store collected data from one view into table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, real-time-data, recursive-triggers

VERSION: Postgres 9.3 / PG-Admin 3

I don't know if there is a way to do this or not - but I have created a view that queries for a real-time data collection of one row. It runs a query and gives a result for that time. Here's my goal:

1. set that query to run every 5 minutes
2. Every time that query runs I want to store that piece of data into another permanent table. So the view collects the data - the table will store the data.

Each time the view refreshes, I lose the previous record - so that's why I'm trying to store the data into another table.

The reason for the query that collects one row at a time for collecting real-time data - but I need a place to store it so I can have a historical data reference for later.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres? Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Not quite clear. What about `insert into permanent_table select now(),* from a_view`?

Comment: Yes! That got me in the direction I needed to go. Thank you!